# Trigger not showing up in code coverage list

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I created a trigger and in order to deploy it to production it needs at least 1% code coverage. I wrote the test class for the trigger, but I'm having a weird issue where the trigger is not showing up in the code coverage list of triggers in the Developer Console. Are other people having the same issue and have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: We really need more information here in order to assist. Make sure you are looking at the same env (prod/dev)

Comment: Does your test case for the trigger pass?

Answer (score 1):

I have had random issues with the developer console. I would try [mavensmate](http://mavensmate.com/), it is a really great ide for SF development and you are able to run tests using a nice UI. Once a test finishes running there are separate sections for class and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Some times developer console does not shows properly. Try ide to run your test class. If it shows some coverage then try migration